# Keybindings not working?

Tags: key-bindings, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs and I've added the following user config:

```
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  "Configuration function for user code.
This function is called at the very end of Spacemacs initialization after
layers configuration.
This is the place where most of your configurations should be done. Unless it is
explicitly specified that a variable should be set before a package is loaded,
you should place your code here."
  (global-set-key (kbd "s-right") 'end-of-line)
  (spacemacs/set-leader-keys "fd" 'ac-php-find-symbol-at-point)   ;goto define
  )
```

However, `s-right` doesn't seem to do what I want. What I want is when I press `CMD + arrow-right` it should jump to the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that in `(kbd "s-right")` the `s` means the Super key, not the Shift key?

And are you aware that the right-arrow key is written `<right>`, not `right`?

For example, Shift + right arrow would be `(kbd "<S-right>")`. You can see this by using `C-h k` and hitting the key sequence.

Comment: I think with `CMD + arrow-right` in the question text, they do know that it isn't Shift.  It sounds like they have `CMD` mapped to Super (or at least that is the intention).

Comment: I think the solution is that they missed the angle brackets.  `(kbd "<s-right>")` is surely what they wanted.

Comment: @g3mini, the crucial bit is that you plug the *same* description of the key sequence into `kbd` as Emacs gives you when you use `C-h k` or `C-h c` to inspect the key sequence.  Emacs uses angle brackets in this instance, so that's also what you should be using with `kbd`.

Comment: @Fólkvangr This is true, and there are various other ways of specifying key sequences too, however my best advice to anyone is to simply use the *same* exact description that Emacs gives you.  Ask Emacs and use what it tells you, and you won't go wrong.

Comment: What @phils said. Use the syntax that Emacs itself uses in `*Help*`, e.g. from `C-h k`. The Emacs *manuals* use a different syntax when talking about physical keys etc. There you will see syntax such as `S-<right>`. But it's best to go with what `*Help*` tells you.